# Ignore footnote index when centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, tabularx

I'm using `tabularx` to have columns with evenly distributed width.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %centered and extended width column type
```

I have a column which always contains four digits, and in consequence of that the content of this column always has the same alignment in every row

```
\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{*{7}{|Y}|}
   \hline
   N° & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
   5463 & some & useful & content & goes & right & here \\ \hline
   4353 & some & other & content & goes & here & too\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sadly, every once in a while I need a footnote, and that screws the alignment up and makes it look bad.

```
\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{*{7}{|Y}|}
   \hline
   N° & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
   5463 & some & useful & content & goes & right & here \\ \hline
   4353\footnote{A footnote is needed here} & some & other & content & goes & here & too\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to center the four digit number, and have the footnote index appear on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide the width of the footnote, which can be accomplished by setting the footnote mark in a zero width box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} %centered and extended width column type

\newcommand{\hfootnote}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\footnotemark}%
  \footnotetext{#1}%
}

\setlength{\textheight}{2.5cm} % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{7}{|Y}|}
\hline
N° & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
5463 & some & useful & content & goes & right & here \\ \hline
4353\hfootnote{abc} & some & other & content & goes & here & too\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=18cm,
paperheight=4cm,
margin=0.5cm
}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

 %S[table-format=2.0]
 %>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{|S[table-format=4.0, table-column-width=.95cm] *{6}{|Y}|}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{|Y|}{N°} & A & B & C & D & E & F \\ \hline
   5463 & some & useful & content & goes & right & here \\ \hline
   4353\footnote{A footnote is needed here} & some & other & content & goes & here & too\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `table-format=4.0` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes.. you are right! Just copied from older file and forgot to change it!... I will update

Comment: Should I read tabularx' documentation on the S meaning and options, or is it a tabular thing?

Comment: No.. it is a  siunitx thing... look here http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf at page 44 and forward